# Unable to ssh localhost without password despite proper perms, key in authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh, localhost, opensuse, hadoop

I have a key `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and I added the pub key to my authorized keys:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I also changed my permissions to 600:

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I checked and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is set for public key auth and has password auth as no.

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

I tried adding:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa localhost > /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

I copied my id:

```
ssh-copy-id myusername@127.0.0.1
```

I restarted the service:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

But despite all that, it still asks for a password! How can i make it not ask for one?

*More Info:*

When I do `ssh localhost` it asks for a password, but when I do `myusername@localhost` it works! Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It was using a different user from `~/.ssh/config` than the one I was logged in as.